# What are the locations of mod_qos configuration(.conf) in linux server?

Tags: linux, apache

I want to implement the rate limiting with Apache using mod_qos. For that I want to add below lines in Apache's configuration:

```
 Sample configuration:
# maximum number of active TCP connections is limited to 512
MaxClients                    512

# limits concurrent requests to the locations:
# - /app/a  max. 200 concurrent requests
# - /app/b and /app/c (together) max. 300 concurrent requests
# - /images max. 100 concurrent requests
QS_LocRequestLimit            /app/a                   200
QS_LocRequestLimitMatch       ^(/app/b/|/app/c/).*$    300
QS_LocRequestLimit            /images                  100
# limits download bandwidth to 5Mbit/sec (resp. 640kbytes/sec)
# for downloads from /app/a:
QS_LocKBytesPerSecLimit       /app/a                   640
```

In which configuration file should I add these lines?

Comment: you can find them by doing `sudo find / -name *.conf` and see the results :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, as your answer find all the conf files present in the particular directory, but here we want to know the name of the conf file for mod_qos as we have not installed mod_qos for example we have httpd.conf file for Apache HTTPD like that if you know the name of file please let me know.

Comment: the protocol is usually service.conf - however, just go to mod_qos project page and it should tell you in the docs there

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to create file yourself

vi /etc/httpd/conf.d/qos.conf

then paste your configurations